# How many different resolutions/orientations should a responsive website cater for?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

It's generally agreed that the optimal website width for a standard display has increased from 800 to 1024+ pixels over the last few years (with websites usually being 960px wide), but with the rise of mobile devices, which resolutions are considered "key" to cater for?

For example, [this website](http://foodsense.is/) has five(!) different layouts, depending on the width of the browser, but most only appear to have two.

Is there a generally agreed upon series of widths that you should *at least* cater for if you wish your site to be responsive? If so, what are they?

Comment: Typically 4 divisions: Mobile, tablet, small screen, large screen.  How you decide to break it up is different depending on what source your reading from but generally all are pretty close.

Comment: You might want to follow [Scott Hanselmans blog](http://www.hanselman.com/) as well.  He talks a lot about trends such as this.

Comment: Technically your site is responsive if you have more than 1. As for an industry standard, we usually have small medium and large, and as kpsuperplane suggested, we use bootstrap. our small is the inclusive full fluid.

Comment: I would suggest that client budget dictates this to some degree.  I am speaking as a freelancer, but even companies with staff for web dev have to budget labor hours.  960px works for most mobile platforms and definitely for desktops.  If you are coding a mobile version, use percentages, and maybe another stylesheet for desktop displays if 960 seems cramped.

Comment: As there is no general agreement on such matters, the question is effectively an opinion poll and call for discussion, rather than a technical question suitable for SO.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, Specifically which articles are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally agree with how [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) does it - One for large devices, one for medium, one for large mobile devices (like tablets) and one final fluid-width one for mobile phone devices (as phone screen resolutions and screen sizes vary all over the place).

These are:

**Extra small devices**
Phones (<768px)

**Small devices**
Tablets (≥768px)

**Medium devices**
Desktops (≥992px)

**Large devices**
Desktops (≥1200px)

Oh and by the way, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) IMO is the best css framework for creating responsive websites that work on basically anything (just remember customize the css to make your site look a bit more original).

Comment: I've added the pixel sizes that Bootstrap uses as default.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Thank you for doing so I appreciate the editing :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your content; your content should drive your breakpoints. Having pre-defined set breakpoints makes assumptions about your content and even more about the devices on which your content will be viewed. If you have a pre-existing responsive grid, you may have to work with the existing breakpoints it provides, but ideally you do it the other way around - start with the narrowest supported width, and figure out where it makes sense to change layouts as the width of your viewport grows. There's no rules or even "industry best practices" anymore about how many breakpoints you should use or define ahead of time.

Comment: Yes, obviously content drives design. It may be important that a given site has 10 breakpoints, for example. That said, given the ubiquity  of portable devices now, there must be widths that are considered "key" in the same way 960px is considered key for desktop displays?

Comment: Actually the ubiquity of devices is driving the conclusion that key breakpoints are ephemeral. See some of Luke Wroblewski's latest presentations ("http://www.lukew.com/presos/preso.asp?31") for the empirical data backing up that assertion.

Comment: "Breakpoints are ephemeral"? You really think they're going to disappear? I will watch the presentation you linked to.